# Sum of the series problem

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

I was doing a programming problem.There i faced the difficulty of solving two series.

The equation which i was asked to solve was $Z_n+Z_{n-1}+2Z_{n-2}$.

Where $Z_{n}$ is given as $P_{n}+S_{n}$.

$$P_{n}= 1^1+2^2+......+n^n$$

$$S_{n}= 1^k+2^k+......+n^k$$

I simplified the given equation ($Z_{n}+Z_{n-1}+2Z_{n-2}$) into a reduced form $-2S_{n}+2p_{n}+n^n+n^k+2(n-1)^k+2(n-1)^n-1$.

The problem i faced is n and k will be given for more than $10000$ testcases .

And the constraints are $1<n<200000000$ , $0<k<1000000$.

I did a simple for loop for adding $P_{n}$ and $S_{n}$ series.But that will time-out.

Is there any formula for that series ? 
Or can it be simplified ?
So that in the future to solve these types of series problems,i can use it.

Thanks.

Comment: You say "The equation which i was asked to solve was $Z_n+Z_{n−1}+2Z_{n−2}$". Where is the equation here?

Comment: There is no simple formula for $P_n$. There is no simple formula for $S_n$. There is no simple formula for $P_n+S_n$. There is no simple formula for $Z_n$. Where does this problem come from, please?

Comment: @ 5xum I have given it at the top.I mean n and k will be given.I have to solve the equation using that values.

Comment: @ gerry http://www.spoj.com/problems/ZSUM/

Comment: The question is for  $Z_n+Z_{n-1}-2Z_{n-2}$ and mod 10000007. Give the problem as it is set, please.

Comment: @ claude Yeah okay.Sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: Are people supposed to get help for spoj problems? Isn't the idea, to do them on your own?